# 'make' error - glib.h no such file or directory on Raspberry Pi

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, raspberrypi

I am trying to compile an Example but I am getting following errors/issues.  I am not sure where the config file and make file is for this package and I don't want to make changes that wipe out everything I have done so far with packages such as "wiringPi" and " bcm2835-1.50" etc.  I need to know what to add to what file and how to run "make" etc on my Raspberry Pi.

gcc -o elinux-example elinux-example.c
In file included from elinux-example.c:11:0:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:26: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` elinux-example.c -o elinux-example
elinux-example.c:14:43: fatal error: /usr/include/glib-2.0/galloca.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

gcc -l/usr/include/glib-2.0 `pkg-config --libs glib` elinux-example.c -o elinux-example
Package glib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'glib' found
In file included from elinux-example.c:13:0:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30:26: fatal error: glib/galloca.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Your assistance is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly does elinux-example.c include the glib header? as `<glib.h>` or as `<glib/glib.h>`? If posible, [edit] your question to include the relevant portion of the .c file

Comment: Thank you for getting back with me.  Below is how it originally appears in the code.

Comment: #include </usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>

Comment: Any update on this, anyone?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `pkg-config --libs --cflags glib-2.0` and `dpkg -V libglib2.0-dev`